# Como puedo hacer seguimiento de correos enviados en php y obtener estadísticas?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, email, phpmailer

necesito obtener quien apertura los correos que envie por php, pienso usar phpmailer, he encontrado soluciones como agregar una imagen pero parece que son enviadas a spam por lo que he leido, quiero obtener quienes los leen y otros datos como hora, ip etc, cualquier información, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo la integración con MailJet, es simple y usando su relay server puedes hacer todo el tracking que necesitas y te da una cuota alta de correos enviados gratis

Comment: Muchas gracias Hiram, se ve genial, me documentare y intentare con ella también! ya tu la usaste con php para el tracking de emails?

Comment: Hola Daniel, si, actualmente lo tengo trabajando con varios proyectos de varios clientes y funciona excelente :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es un **email tracker**, así como lo hace [Mailtrack](https://mailtrack.io) en gmail. Pues te recomiendo que pruebes con estos recursos:

1. [PHP Email Tracker](https://github.com/brampauwelyn/php-email-tracker) <--- Este es mejor si solo quieres la lógica y ya tienes tus diseños.
2. [Formget](https://www.formget.com/tracking-email/)

Comment: Hola, lo que me piden implementar es que cuando se envíen  correos a suscriptores, saber cuales los abrieron, hora/fecha, ip, entre otros datos y mostrar todo eso como datos estadísticos, si tipo gráficos, no solo saber si no abrieron, voy a mirar esas sugerencia, mil gracias Jesús!